# My local images under /public/images doesn't load in my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I have a component which is Portafolio.js where I am using the map function to get every object on a "trabajos.js" file where I have all the objects with its properties. I am trying to show an image to every of those objects using their id's. For some reason it doesn't work, I have checked the routes, names, spaces, etc.

Portafolio.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { trabajos } from './datos/trabajos';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

export const Portafolio = () => {
  return (
    <div>

      {
        trabajos.map( trabajo => {
          return (
            <article key={trabajo.id}>
              <div className='mask'>
                <img src={"/images/" + trabajo.id + ".png" } alt='hola'/>
              </div>
              <span>{trabajo.categorias}</span>
              <h2><Link to={trabajo.url} target='__blank'>{trabajo.nombre}</Link></h2>
              <h3>{trabajo.tecnologias}</h3>
            </article>
          )
          
        })
      }



    </div>

    
  )
}
```

And here is my trabajos.js where I have the objects:

```
export const trabajos = [
    {
        'id': 'moviehub',
        'nombre': 'Movie Hub',
        'url': 'https://tonychongng.github.io/moviehub/',
        'tecnologias': 'HTML, CSS, JS, REACT',
        'categorias': 'Desarrollo Web'
    },

    {
        'id': 'todolist',
        'nombre': 'To-do List',
        'url': 'https://tonychongng.github.io/todo_app/',
        'tecnologias': 'HTML, CSS, JS, REACT',
        'categorias': 'Desarrollo Web'
    },

    {
        'id': 'starbucksclone',
        'nombre': 'Starbucks Clone',
        'url': 'https://tonychongng.github.io/Starbucks-Clone/',
        'tecnologias': 'HTML, CSS, JS',
        'categorias': 'Desarrollo Web'
    }
];
```

As I said, the trabajos.js is under public/images/my-images.png so I believe the src="/images" is correct.

[Here is a pic of my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDVKR.png)

I already tried to copy the relative path and the path of those images in src but still doesnt work.

Other thing that I tried is to use in Portafolio.js this line of code: . I thought it could be a problem for the map function but that line of code still doesn't work.

Comment: Please show what generated URL you get and what actual URL should be for first element in array.

Comment: When I code: `{console.log("/images/" + trabajo.id + ".png")}` I get three lines of code in my console because I have 3 objects. I get: `/images/moviehub.png`, `/images/todolist.png`, and `/images/starbucksclone.png`  in my console, which match with each of their names and .png. The images folder is under the public folder so I believe it is correct.

Comment: Don't just "believe", take that `/images/starbucksclone.png` and visit in your browser `http://example.com/images/starbucksclone.png` - if it shows image - path is correct, if not - first find out what actual URL must be (via browser, not React)

Comment: Oh my bad, I am new into programming, I tried that but it says "no routes matches location". So the url is incorrect. Still don't know what to do though, I will try things

Comment: try `src={require("/images/" + trabajo.id + ".png")}`

Comment: still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using a `<Link>` item from `react-router-dom` while supplying your other GitHub projects as a `to` parameter.

It is most probably the reason why your app is failing.
First, stuff around "[Client-side routing](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/overview)" should be refreshed (if you are familiar with this concept already, that's good).

Essentially, client-side routing should match paths/routes inside the same project/origin, e.g.

```
https://tonychongng.github.io/react
https://tonychongng.github.io/react/todo-app
https://tonychongng.github.io/react/starbucks-clone
etc...
```

In the situation above, `https://tonychongng.github.io/react` would be the root of your app, and you could actually `<Link>` to them like this:

```js
===== Portafolio.js =====
...
return (
  ...
  <Link to="todo-app" />
  <Link to="starbucks-clone" />
  ...
);
```

and that would take you to the routes mentioned earlier - still inside the same root/app.

===

Summary/tl;dr: If you want to link to your other GitHub projects from within this "Portafolio" app, you need to use a good old `<a>` HTML element, not `<Link>` from `react-router-dom` as it is for client-side routing only:

```html
<a href={trabajo.url}>{trabajo.nombre}</a>
```

Hope it clarifies the situation a bit. Have a great day!

Comment: i mean, thank you for that, but my problem was that my local images are not working